# passport.js calling this.somemethod throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'somemethod'

Tags: node.js, typescript, passport.js

I am calling the following from one class:

```
router.post('/login', ctrlAuth.login);
```

Then the ctrlAuth is from another class:

```
login(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('ldapauth', function (err, user, info) {
        ... // handling err and !user
        ...
        if (user) this.processUser(req, res);
    })(req, res);
}

private processUser(req, res) {...}
```

Then I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'processUser' of undefined

So far, this is how I did it, but still doesn't work:

```
login(req, res) {
    const callback = ((err, user, info) => {
        if (user) this.processUser(req, res);
    }).bind(this);
    passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}, callback)(req, res);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Use an arrow function instead

Comment: i updated my question.  I actually tried const self = this; also arrow function and the bind(this), but i can't get it to work.

Comment: I finally solved it.  I use multiple callbacks in router.post('/login', ctrlAuth.login, ctrlAuth.processUser);  and inside the login method, i just called next()

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I thought of fixing this:

1. Bind the ctrlAuth to the method:

   `router.post('/login', ctrlAuth.login.bind(ctrlAuth));`
2. Create another class and use it as next callback:

   `router.post('/login', ctrlAuth.login, ctrlAuth.processUser);`

   Inside ctrAuth.login, I call on `next();`